# \cite within figure \caption

Tags: captions, citing

I'm trying to put a \cite within a figure caption, but when the list of references is being built, it places all \cites inside figure captions first, and only then it starts placing all the other references in the document.

I know that this question has already been asked multiple times and i found several answers around the Web, but nobody of them seems to solve my problem.

I've tried:

- To use \protect\cite
- To use package notoccite
- To use \caption[text without cite command]{text with \cite}

Here's my minimal program:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}   
\usepackage{lipsum}           
\usepackage{url}              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, backend=biber, hyperref]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliografia.bib}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{notoccite}


\begin{document}
\author{Me}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

%...
\section{}
\lipsum[1]\cite{focardi}



\appendix
\section{Viscosità attesa teoricamente}
\label{app:appA}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{tabviscos.png}
    \caption[Caption]{Viscosità di soluzioni acquose di glicerina ($cP$) \protect\cite{glic}}
    \label{fig:tabvisc}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

I'm working with Overleaf

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Yes @Mico, that was the point. I've edited my post

Comment: With the method you employ in the code example, you'll need to re-run LaTeX at least twice to see the expected output in (a) the List of Figures and (b) the numbering of the bibliographic items. Did you re-run LaTeX twice after adding the optional, citation-free argument to `\caption`?

Comment: Yes, i've run it multiple times both with Overleaf and TeXStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `sorting=none` option to `biblatex` seems to resolve your issue:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[english, italian]{babel}   
\usepackage{lipsum}           
\usepackage{url}              
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, backend=biber, hyperref,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{notoccite}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{focardi,
  author = {Citation, Text},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{glic,
  author = {Citation, Caption},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\author{Me}
\title{Title}
\maketitle

%...
\section{}
\lipsum[1]\cite{focardi}



\appendix
\section{Viscosità attesa teoricamente}
\label{app:appA}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{tabviscos.png}
    \caption[Caption]{Viscosità di soluzioni acquose di glicerina ($cP$) \cite{glic}}
    \label{fig:tabvisc}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]


\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solved perfectly, very thanks!